# Definition of matplotlib.pyplot.axes.bbox

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't understand the definition of `axes.bbox`. For example:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> f, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax.bbox
TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ 0.125,  0.1  ],\n       [ 0.9  ,  0.9  ]])'), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ 0.,  0.],\n       [ 8.,  6.]])'), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  80.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.]])))))
```

1. What do these values mean? I would have assumed that 4 numbers would be sufficient to define a rectangle. Obviously more information is stored here.
2. For the commands like `ax.figure.canvas.blit(bbox)` I need to define a value for the bbox. How can I manually define a `bbox` of particular  dimensions (let's say for the lower right quarter of the axes)?

Comment: It is the bounds + how to it from figure fraction units -> screen (ie pixel) units.

Comment: Thanks tcaswell! And how do I define a `bbox` - object  with the relative coordinates `x = 0.5 ... 1 ` , `y = 0 .. 0.3`   as input for the `blit()` command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. The value you see displayed is a bit of a complicated `Bbox`, with nested transforms that it automatically applies.  Firstly, it is a [`TransformedBbox`](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.TransformedBbox) instance - quoting from the docs:

   > A Bbox that is automatically transformed by a given transform.

   the representation of it in the console that you show above displays two things (comma separated) - the main `Bbox` upon which it is based, and the `transform` that it applies.  The `transform` in this case is a [`BboxTransformTo`](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.BboxTransformTo) object, which:

   > BboxTransformTo is a transformation that linearly transforms points from the unit bounding box to a given Bbox.

   In your case, the `transform` itself is based upon a `TransformedBBox` which again has a `Bbox` upon which it is based and a transform - for this nested instance an [`Affine2D`](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D) transform.

   The purpose of the transforms (I believe) is to translate from relative co-ordinates to screen units.

   In your example, you might find that the points you expected to see are given by

   ```
   >>> ax.bbox.get_points()
   array([[  80.,   48.],
          [ 576.,  432.]])
   ```

   All the code for this is in [available on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/transforms.py) if you want to convince yourself exactly what is being displayed.
2. From the documentation, you can instantiate a [Bbox object](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox) with the four numbers you imagine, e.g.

   ```
   from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

   my_blit_box = Bbox(np.array([[x0,y0],[x1,y1]])
   ```

   You could also use one of the [static methods](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox.from_bounds), e.g.

   ```
   my_blit_box = Bbox.from_bounds(x0, y0, width, height)
   ```

#### Caveat

I haven't got your use case, so can't say whether rolling your own `Bbox` and passing it to `blit()` will work directly for your case.

However, it's likely to be a really complicated way round to do what you want.

Assming that you want to animate a plot - you can usually pass `blit=True` in as an argument to the animation functions and they will sort this out themselves.  [The docs are here](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html).  There are [some examples here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html), including ones with subplots.  As a skeleton - you might do something like

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)

    # Code to actually put data on your 3 axes

animation.TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, interval=50, blit=True)
```

If you want to refresh one subplot out of many - passing in the `ax.bbox` directly into the `blit` function should work.

Note that most of the examples given don't define their own Bbox, but rather pass in a Bbox derived from an `axes`, `figure` or `canvas` into `blit`. Note also that passing nothing into `ax.figure.canvas.blit()` will redraw the whole canvas (the default option - although I can't see why you'd want to do that).

Comment: Many Thanky Richard! The issue seems to be complexer than initial thougth. My use case is not to Special: Simply moving a picture with a mouse.    However it showed unexpected behavior. In the debugging I was not sure if I have used `blit` with the correct `bbox`.  Since I couldn't find the rrquired info in the `__doc__` and web I raised the question here. I now understand that the `blit(ax.box)` should be safe. Many thanks.

Comment: If I (with this new knowledge) still cannot solve my problem I'll set-up a new question. In order to have good readablilty for other SO-users, i propose to leave this Q&A as it is and not mix it with a different Problem.

Comment: Ok, found my bug: In the function `canvas.restore_region(bg,bbox, xy)` i was mixing the meaning of `bbox`and `xy`. Your clearification helped me in isolating the bug.

Comment: @Richard: I got notice that this is now a popular question (>1000). Seems that your detailed explainations are also helpfull for many other users.

Comment: Famous question 10000 views :-)