# What's the meaning of clip_box in Matplotlib Artist?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am testing the `clip_box` feature of Artist using the code snippet below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots(1, 2)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 8, 5, 2]

line_a, = ax[0].plot(x, y, color='red', linewidth=3.0)
line_b, = ax[1].plot(x, y, color='red', linewidth=3.0)

boundingbox = Bbox(np.array([[0, 0], [3, 9]]))
line_b.set_clip_box(boundingbox)
line_b.set_clip_on(True)

plt.show()
```

What I expect is the last part of `line_b` will be cut out by the clip box, and `line_b` will be a bit shorter than `line_a`.

It turns out that there's nothing left on the second subplot. It's totally empty. Is my understanding of the `clip_box` wrong or are there some issues in the code snippet?

Comment: where does `Bbox` come from?

Comment: from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

Comment: @MagnusO_O, 3.6.0

Answer (score 2):

I've spent some time reading about Bboxes in Matplotlib and they are pretty complicated. The [`set_clip_box`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_box.html) method you refer to has not got very helpful documentation, and the examples of its use both use the `bbox` of an Axes, which is a nested transformation; ie `_, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.bbox` is a TransformedBbox based on a linear transform of another TransformedBbox based on an Affine2D transform of a plain Bbox! (All of this explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29822137/6220759).)

It seems that these involve transformations between different sets of co-ordinates; in the case of a regular `Axes` it is between x- and y-values, pixels, and the specific adaptations to screen size. I would be happy to hear from someone who knows more about Bboxes why your Bbox acts the way it does. But what you want to achieve can be done much more easily, using a `FancyBboxPatch` (a `Rectangle` patch would work just as well):

```
from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 8, 5, 2]

line_a, = ax[0].plot(x, y, color='red', linewidth=3.0)
line_b, = ax[1].plot(x, y, color='red', linewidth=3.0)


bb = Bbox([[0, 0], [3, 9]])
ax[1].add_patch(FancyBboxPatch((bb.xmin, bb.ymin), bb.width, bb.height, boxstyle="square",
                               ec='white', fc='white', zorder=2.1))
```

[image]

(*ec* and *fc* are edge colour and fill colour; zorder determines the artist order. Lines are 2, so we just need out Bbox patch to be slightly higher.)

Answer (score 2):

The "natural" clip box for the right hand side plot is `ax[1].bbox`. Finding its extent tells us what units should be used to specify the clip box `Bbox`.

Since we don't add the `Bbox` instance to any axes when we create, it could only be relative to the figure. When we print `ax[1].bbox`, we can see that its size is to be specified in pixels.

It's indeed much simpler to use a Rectangle or [Polygon](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html) to specify the clip box because they can be added to axes. Using `'none'` color for its `facecolor` could be more convenient because it's figure style-independent.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

fig = plt.figure(dpi=89)
ax = fig.subplots(1, 2)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 8, 5, 2]

line_a, = ax[0].plot(x, y, color='red', linewidth=3.0)
line_b, = ax[1].plot(x, y, color='red', linewidth=3.0)

print(ax[1].bbox, '\n', ax[1].bbox.extents)
# the line above prints
# TransformedBbox(
#     Bbox(x0=0.5477272727272726, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.8999999999999999, y1=0.88),
#     BboxTransformTo(
#         TransformedBbox(
#             Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=6.393258426966292, y1=4.797752808988764),
#             Affine2D().scale(178.0))))
# [ 623.31363636   93.94       1024.2         751.52      ]
# 178.0 is 2 * dpi, I believe the doubling happens because of what screen I have got

boundingbox =  Bbox.from_extents([623.31363636, 93.94, 900.2, 751.52])
print(boundingbox, '\n', boundingbox.extents)
# the line above prints
# Bbox(x0=623.31363636, y0=93.94, x1=900.2, y1=751.52) 
# [623.31363636  93.94       900.2        751.52      ]
line_b.set_clip_box(boundingbox)
line_b.set_clip_on(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks! 2 quick questions: 1) I get a different output for `ax[1].bbox`, did you use a different command? 2) is there any case where I would want to use a clip_box?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander: thanks for the bounty :)  1) Assuming you use the same dpi, its possibly because you have got a different screen (I have got a MacBook pro with Retina screen). I don't think the exact number of pixels matters, you just take what you have got, and map (transform) it to the axes' coordinates. If it's unclear, I can add a quick example later.

Comment: 2) I have used clip boxes for drawing (you can do pretty drawings with matplotlib!) and to make sure subordinate axes (axes on axes) stay within the parent axes box.

Comment: thanks for that. re 1), I agree that I probably have a different dpi, but  specifically I meant that `ax[1].bbox` returns just the object repr, ie `<matplotlib.transforms.TransformedBbox at 0x2a3eded30>`, not any more detail

Comment: @JoshFriedlander - probably IDE-specific. I use VSC, and this is how my printout looks. The other way is to debug and expand the `ax[1].bbox` object